# I'm trying to merge the columns of two dataframes based on some conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networking, automation

I'm sorry, I know this question has already been asked, but I haven't managed to optimize/correct my results using the existing help.

I have two pandas dataframe :

**df_1** : Contains the whole information bank about switches from 'a' to 'z'

```
Index localHost  localInt vlans
 0    switch_a   Te1/0/1  100,200,300
 1    switch_a   Te1/0/2  252,478,963
 2    switch_b   Te1/0/1  154,586,354
...
```

**df_2** : Miss vlans information for some specific switches (all located in df_1 but not in the same order)

```
Index localHost  localInt vlans
 0    switch_a   Te1/0/1  
 1    switch_a   Te1/0/2  
 2    switch_z   Te1/0/1  
...
```

I would like to update df_2 or create a new dataframe (doesn't matter much) that will merge the df_1 and df_2 vlans data.

The only condition for the merged is that the localHost and localInt value in the same row are equal in both dataframes when reporting the vlans.

I first tried using a mask to isolate the only relevant rows :

```
for index, row in df_1.iterrows() :
  switch_name = row['localHost']
  switch_interface = row['localInt']
  switch_vlans = row['vlans']
    
  mask = (df_2['localHost'] == switch_name) & (df_2['localInt'] == switch_interface)
  df_2.loc[mask, 'vlans'] = switch_vlans
```

It seems to be working, but I don't understand why only every other line is processed:

```
Index localHost  localInt vlans
 0    switch_a   Te1/0/1  100,200,300
 1    switch_a   Te1/0/2  
 2    switch_z   Te1/0/1  265,477,111
...
```

Then I tried using a nested loop but the results was the same.
do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Could you please include the desired output so I (or someone else) can try to generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should use `.merge`:

```py
out = df2.drop(columns="vlans").merge(
    df1[["localHost", "localInt", "vlans"]], on=["localHost", "localInt"], how="left"
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   Index localHost localInt        vlans
0      0  switch_a  Te1/0/1  100,200,300
1      1  switch_a  Te1/0/2  252,478,963
2      2  switch_z  Te1/0/1  265,477,111
```

---

Initial dataframe `df1`:

```
   Index localHost localInt        vlans
0      0  switch_a  Te1/0/1  100,200,300
1      1  switch_a  Te1/0/2  252,478,963
2      2  switch_b  Te1/0/1  154,586,354
3      3  switch_z  Te1/0/1  265,477,111
```

Initial dataframe `df2`:

```
   Index localHost localInt  vlans
0      0  switch_a  Te1/0/1    NaN
1      1  switch_a  Te1/0/2    NaN
2      2  switch_z  Te1/0/1    NaN
```